# Vertical/horizontal view in superview - storyboard iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I need to center align a view (Inner View) vertically and horizontally in superview (Main View).

Here's the view controller:

[image]

I have set the centerX and centerY constraints properly. But Xcode shows error for missing constraints as given here:

[image]

This is the current layout. I want to center align Inner View vertically and horizontally in the screen. Or is there any other way to achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying a little too much on **center** constraints.

Setting `centerX` and `centerY` on a subview does not determine the width and height of its superview, which is why you are getting layout errors.

Select your `Sign Up View` and add Leading and Trailing constraints of Zero - that will give `Inner View` a width, and then remove the `Sign Up View.centerX = centerX` constraint.

That should satisfy the `X Position` requirements.

Next, with your `Sign Up View` selected, add a Bottom constraint of Zero, and remove the `Sign Up View.centerY = centerY` constraint...

That should satisfy the `Y Position` requirements.

The important thing to remember is that you need a complete "chain" of constraints for each axis.

Here's a screen-cap of my constraints. Note that I constrained the Top of `Sign Up View` to the Top of `avocado-signup + 56` (your actual image size is probably different):

[image]